# Querying CosmosDB Collection with property that have the same property but with different types

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Lets suppose that I have a Cosmos Db collection that owns the documents explained by these 2 classes

```cs
public class DocumentBase {
    public string DocumentType {get; set;}
}
public class DocumentA : DocumentBase {
   public string PropertyA {get; set;}
}

public class DocumentB : DocumentBase {
   public string[] PropertyA {get; set;}
}
```

How can I query this collection in a way that for DocumentA the clause is PropertyA = value and for DocumentB the clause is PropertyA contains Value?
The Query needs to be generated automatically depending on input values.

EDIT: Updated question content.

Comment: Does the invoker have a different code path that determines which type is used?  That would be the place to create two different access patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query below. If `propA` is undefined or not the appropriate type that part of the expression results in a `false` and not throw any error. So you can safely query over both types.

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.propA, "myValue") OR c.propA = "myValue"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can logically separate your documents in Cosmos to ensure you are querying the correct ones. I've used two approaches:

- Use a `type` property to distinguish between types
- Use the type as (the/part of the) partition key

In either case, you can add the type as part of the query, either as a WHERE clause like `WHERE c.type = 'DocumentA' AND ... <other expressions>`, or a just with the partition key in the SDK operation when partitioned by type.

With this setup, there's no problem with querying against a property of the same name using different expression types. Of course, it might be less confusing to use different names.

Comment: I already have this setup in place (the code example is just a reduced version) my problem is that my query has to traverse the whole collection filtering on all document types being somewhat ignorant of the "cardinality" of the properties (single vs array)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you say the query "traverses whole collection". If you partition by type, queries on a given type partition will be efficient single-partition queries by definition.